# How to create a tutorial on how to use a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have tried googling this with many combinations of words but the results returned were always about creating a website.

What I want to do is, when a user opens the web page, he will get a little introduction, something like in codility, for example you can click on this button to do something and at the same time highlight the button. How is that done? I am not looking for ready made code, just some instructions to point me in the right direction, or a tutorial on how to do that.

**EDIT:**

I would have deleted this question if I thought it does not conform to the rules of the website. I don't think it is off topic because it can happen to anyone to not know a specific word, which is tour not tutorial. I am leaving it here so that the next person who searches for this knows that the word is tour not tutorial. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "tour" not tutorial. **tour library for website**

Comment: I don't get the problem. just google js product tour and you will find libraries such as intro.js, jquery crumble ect. if your app needs registration, add a db table where you check if the intro was already done or cancelled and you are ready.

Comment: @HorstJahns Well, I didn't think of trying the word tour

Comment: You know, not being able to think of a specific word can be a problem for any non native speaker, it doesn't deserve all this hate. I think my question is a totally legit question, and it could help someone in the future, otherwise I would have deleted it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `tour` or `features introduction`.
A quick Google search came up with:

1. [Angular-tour](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour)
2. [Angular-ui-tour](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour)
3. [NZTour](http://nozzle.github.io/nzTour/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function (JavaScript/JQuery) that targets the elements you want to highlight (buttons, divs or inputs) and displays a small tooltip/infotip containing instructions and navigation buttons, clicking a button pops up an other tooltip in a different location.

If you're using angular, you can use "website tour" directives/modules that does that out of the box.